# Any way to distinguish between "people user accounts" and "computer user accounts"?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

When querying Active Directory for users - is there a way to filter out user accounts created for computers? Ideally a way which is common across most typical networks. e.g.:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(new DirectoryEntry([Users_OU_root]));    
ds.filter = "(&(objectClass=User)([CRITERIA_TO_FILTER_OUT_COMPUTER_USER_ACCOUNTS]))";    
ds.FindAll();    
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // do something here....     
}

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD:

Computer accounts will show up as `ComputerPrincipal` (derived from `Principal`) - so you can easily keep users and computer accounts apart.

If you cannot or don't want to move to S.DS.AM - you can also keep user and computers apart by using the `objectCategory` instead of the objectClass in your LDAP filter. `objectCategory` is beneficial anyway, since it's indexed, and not multi-valued - so query performance will be much better.

For a real-life user, use `objectCategory = Person`, while for a computer, use `objectCategory = Computer` in your LDAP filter.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I agree with the answer. Active-Directory remain an LDAP server. Here is the filter you are looking for :

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(...))
```

'`objectCategory=user`' is a shortcut for '`objectCategory=CN=User,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=dom,DC=fr`' understood by Active-Directory but it's also a way in others Directories, that's why I put an answer, even if another answer is accepted.